# Write big dataframe to excel pandas

Tags: python, sql, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have table with ~1 million records and i want write this records into excel file. But script eat a lot of RAM, ~10gb+. Are there any other ways besides to_excel?

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
PB_array= ['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01']
for PB in PB_array:
    Filename=f'name-{PB}.xlsx'
    con = Cx_Oracle.connect(user='',password='',dsn='')
    data_exel=pd.read_sql(f"""Select * from table1 where day=date'{PB}'

                          """)

    data_exel.to_excel(Filename,index=False) 
    con.close()
```

Comment: can you keep the `con` connection outside the loop and try

Comment: df.to_csv? I should be faster

Comment: add a `gzip` compression to that csv ^ and you'll be surprised at how quick & small the file is.

Comment: df.to_csv works well, but need .xlsx, in this format they ask at work

Comment: Check whether all the data is being read into memory (I'm not familiar with pd.read_sql).  You may want (or need) to process batches of data, following something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315171/batch-downloading-of-table-using-cx-oracle/57331008#57331008